# Mimetype of file uploaded to django

Tags: android, django, file

I'm trying to upload a file to a django server from an android phone, and i'm getting a strange mimetype. My code utilizes the Asynchrnous HTTP request client, and I'm using the below code:

```
File file = new File(/*Get file*/)
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("file", file);

getAsyncHttpClient().post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onSuccess(final JSONObject obj) {
        Log.i(TAG, obj.toString());
    }
});
```

The content-type I'm getting on the server from a django `FileField` is `application/octet-stream`. Is there anyway to get the real mimetype to be passed in? I have been researching on this for sometime.

I read these below links:

[Uploading an image from Android (with Android Asynchronous Http Client) to rails server (with paperclip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245469/uploading-an-image-from-android-with-android-asynchronous-http-client-to-rails)

[Android image file sent to php upload image file is application/octet-stream type and not image/jpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778151/android-image-file-sent-to-php-upload-image-file-is-application-octet-stream-typ)

Is there something else I should be passing into the Android Asynchronous Http Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I didn't see this before.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html

You can just do:

```
params.put("file", file, mimetype);
```